# Webdriver latency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, webdriver

Is anyone else experiencing a latency issue with Webdriver? I have it running on Cucumber with Capybara. And it takes more than 30 seconds or even minutes to fill in a form. For some reason, it will fill in one field and then pause before filling in another field when both are referenced by id.

Also, I'm running into Timeout Errors because of this latency. (But they are erratic...)

There isn't anything special about the fields. They appear on page load and there is no Ajax on this page.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the error:

```
execution expired (Timeout::Error)
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60:in `rbuf_fill'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2026:in `read_status_line'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2015:in `read_new'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request_without_webmock'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1037:in `request_without_webmock'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
     /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request_without_webmock'
```

**Edit:** This might be related to the fact that I had a Firefox instance already open when I ran the Cucumber tests. Although the frequency of timeouts decreased, I still get them often enough that I think it's still an issue.

**Edit2:** Feature file will specify a step:
`And I complete personal info`

The step will be further defined as other steps:

```
And /^I complete personal info$/ do
  fill_in('first_id', :with => "foo")
  fill_in('second_id', :with => "bar")
  ...more fill_ins...
end
```

Capybara will find `first_id` sometimes and the rest of my scenario executes fine. Other times, it will time out. It's very unpredictable, in my opinion. Still other times, it'll find `first_id` but not find `second_id`. These `id`s do indeed exist on the page, by the way.

I should have included more information about the error. It will often look like this:

```
...all that stuff I included in the error above...
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:107
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:11:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
/my feature file:30:in 'Then we verify stuff we just filled out'
```

`Then we verify stuff we just filled out` is defined with these additional steps:

```
And %{I should see "foo"}
And %{I should see "bar"}
```

I hope this extra information helps! If you need anything else, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean webdriver or selenium-webdriver? Also, what versions of webdriver, cucumber, capybara, rails (looks like ruby enterprise edition 1.8.7)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the other Firefox instance you have running. I get timeouts from time to time using your stack of Cucumber, Capybara, and WebDriver -- but they never relate to other running FF instances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with webmock, but looking at the backtrace it's not unlikely that's the culprit - since WebDriver uses HTTP to communicate with Firefox, and specifically Net::HTTP by default.

To confirm this, you can [tell WebDriver to use Curb instead](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Using_Curb_or_your_own_HTTP_client), which hopefully won't be affected by what webmock does.

Comment: I'm confused about why this needs to be confirmed. Also, it's unclear to me what it means to use Net::HTTP by default. Finally, I don't have Curb or net-http-persistent gem installed. I mean, I can certainly install it, but, again, I'm unsure why I need to.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. WebDriver by default uses Net::HTTP to send commands to the Firefox extension used to control the browser. Webmock AFAIK will monkey patch Net::HTTP, which is the most likely cause of the issue. If using a HTTP stack that Webmock doesn't touch resolves the problem, we've confirmed that Webmock is the cause of the issue and be one step closer to figure out what's going on.

Comment: After looking closer, it looks like WebMock will mock Curb requests as well. It would be helpful if you could provide a simple script that will reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you experienced was caused by WebMock which broke default Net::HTTP beheviour. This issue is now fixed in WebMock 1.7.0